# Tableau: Passing a value in a Webpage input box

Tags: tableau-api

I have a tableau report that I created a URL Action Menu that points to a website URL

**For confidentiality the URL is not active. I'm just illustrating the sample URL path**

**Tableau Dashboard**

[image]

What I want to set-up is when the "Submit" link is clicked, the website is opened and the ID is automatically entered in the web page input box.

**Web Page to auto enter the ID**

[image]

How do I incorporate in the URL to automatically send the ID value in the web page input box

Comment: It's going to depend on how the web page is programmed. If the webpage accepts URL parameters and the web page programmer has set it up so that a parameter gets put into the text box, it will work. This isn't a Tableau question. It's all dependent on the web page and how it is programmed and set up.

Comment: The source of information is coming from a tableau report as I stated in the above pictures and description.

Comment: the only way this will work is if the web page has been programmed to accept data as a URL query parameter and has been programmed to put that data into the text box. Talk to the site's owner or better yet, the website developer. If the web page is not programmed to do this, nothing you do in Tableau will change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass field values in the URL

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions_fieldvalues_url.html